# Protect file from being changed

Tags: linux, security, file-io, filesystems

How to make all `write()`s to a file fail *silently* so that the caller thinks that the data has been written, but actually nothing was written (at FS level)?
The file's contents must be still readable (so linking to `/dev/null` isn't an option).

Answer (score 0):

Possible options:

- Use `LD_PRELOAD` to substitute `write()` with our own implementation. It wont work in general case, since `write()` is not the only way to change file contents.
- Use `FUSE` to create your own filesystem that provides intended behaviour. It will work in general case, but requires more coding. There are also some python bindings.

You could try to search for various filesystems implemented using `FUSE`, probably you'll find something that allows you to avoid coding at all.